# Ocean Monuments on Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, minecraft-legacy-console

I'm playing minecraft on my Xbox One, and it recently received an update, adding all sorts of new blocks including wet and dry sponges. I have searched in vain for an ocean monument, and I would like to know, are there even any ocean monuments at the newest update for Xbox One?

Comment: Are you playing on a new world or is this a migrated old world?  old worlds that have been updated to the new update don't include newer features such as ocean monuments in their world generation.  Try creating a new world and looking on there.

Comment: I have explored on creative, and in new worlds, but I never find anything cool.

Comment: Dare i suggest that you google search for xbox 1 seeds containing ocean monuments?  Or do you not like using seeds found online?

Comment: I just googled quickly and saw a few seeds but i don't have an xbox 1 so couldn't test them :/

Comment: @Jcraft153 will you tell me what they are so I can test it? but put it in answer form so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a seed for an ocean monument for Xbox one edition, seed: - 6183297696734005648  I found this on the Minecraft Xbox one edition subreddit , https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftOne/ this is a reddit that you may also find usefull for any other questions you have as all the people there are xbox one  players. (I think!)  ~Jay

Comment: Ah!, there are 2 seeds on the specific page i looked at, the link is here <https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftOne/comments/3xds9t/seed_ocean_monument_near_spawn/>